# JPA CascadeType Persist doesn't work with spring data

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, user:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq_gen")
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 6, max = 100)
    private String password;

}
```

And verification:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Verification {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private User user;

}
```

And I save these entities in this method:

```
@Transactional
    public void registerUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(DigestUtils.md5Hex(user.getPassword()));
        String code = RandomStringUtils.random(20, true, true);
        Verification verification;
        while(true) {
            if (!verificationRepository.existsByCode(code)) {
                verification = new Verification(code, user);
                break;
            } else {
                code = RandomStringUtils.random(20, true, true);
            }
        }
        verificationRepository.save(verification);
    }
```

But CascadeType persist doesn't work, it throws the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
  Подробности: Failing row contains (Oda2AolKrQXYSxuVmclO, null).
```

But when I change cascade type to MERGE, it works. And I don't understand why, because I create new User and new Verification at the same time. And first I need to save the user, then the verification. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data JPA uses the ID to determine if the instance is new or not. Since it seems you are setting the id to a non-null value Spring Data JPA considers it an existing entity and calls `merge` instead of `persist`.

Read ["Saving Entities" in the Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) about how to tweak that behavior.

I recommend thinking in terms of Domain Driven Design and Aggregates/Aggregate Roots in order to determine the entities which should be linked via `Cascade.ALL` + `DELETE_ORPHAN` and those without any cascading and separate repositories instead.

I recommend reading "[Advancing Enterprise DDD](http://scabl.blogspot.com/p/advancing-enterprise-ddd.html)" about the topic.