# Using composite identifiers @EmbeddedId with @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-cascade

My example below is for learning purpose. The goal is to create some examples using the [Composite identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-aggregated). Unfortunately, I'm getting some strange results.

**Entities**: `Course`, `Teacher`, `CoursePk`.

Each course should be given by only one `Teacher`.

I'm using a bidirectional relation `@OneToOne()` between the class `Teacher` and the class `Course`.

Each `Course` contains a composite primary key. In my example I'm simplifying and I'm using a composite primary key that use only one attribute.

The goal of my example is to persist the associated teacher when the course object is persisted.

The `Teacher` Class:

```
@Entity(name = "Teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "officialTeacher")
    private Course course;

    //setter getter constructors are omitted for brevity
}
```

The `Course` class:

```
@Entity(name = "Course")
public class Course {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CoursePk pkCourse;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Teacher officialTeacher;

    //setter getter constructors are omitted for brevity
}
```

The `CoursePk` that should represents a composite primary key.

```
@Embeddable
public class CoursePk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "courseName")
    private Integer courseId;
}
```

My running example:

```
private void composedPrimaryKey() {
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher("Jeff", "Boss");
        CoursePk composedPK = new CoursePk(1);
        Course course = new Course(composedPK, teacher);
        Course savedCourse = courseRepository.save(course);
    }
```

With that my tables looks like:

**course table**

```
course_name | official_teacher_id
     1      |      1
```

**teacher table**

```
id  | first_name |last_name
 1  |   null     |  null
```

As you can see, the information of the teacher are not persisted, but only the id field.

Magically when I change the cascade type to `CascadeType.ALL`, everything is persisted.

```
id  | first_name |last_name
 1  |   Jeff     |  Boss
```

Could someone explains why it didn't works with only `CascadeType.PERSIST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Spring Data JPA: `CrudRepository.save(…)` method behaviour

Given that Spring Data JPA is used, there is some specifics on how the `CrudRepository.save(…)` method detects the method call to be performed: either `EntityManager.persist(…)` or `EntityManager.merge(…)`:

> ## 5.2.1. Saving Entities
>
> Saving an entity can be performed with the `CrudRepository.save(…)` method. It persists or merges the given entity by using the underlying JPA `EntityManager`. If the entity has not yet been persisted, Spring Data JPA saves the entity with a call to the `entityManager.persist(…)` method. Otherwise, it calls the `entityManager.merge(…)` method.
>
> ### Entity State-detection Strategies
>
> Spring Data JPA offers the following strategies to detect whether an entity is new or not:
>
> - Id-Property inspection (**default**): By default Spring Data JPA inspects the identifier property of the given entity. If the identifier property is null, then the entity is assumed to be new. Otherwise, it is assumed to be not new.
>
> <…>
>
> — [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites).

## Back to the question

Coming back to the piece of code mentioned in the question.
Since the identifier property (the primary key) of the `Course` instance is not null, Spring Data JPA considers it as an existing (not new) entity and calls the `EntityManager.merge(…)` method instead of the `EntityManager.persist(…)` method.

## Additional references

Additionally, please, refer to the related question: [java - JPA CascadeType Persist doesn't work with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800132/jpa-cascadetype-persist-doesnt-work-with-spring-data).

Comment: Thanks for the clear response. I'm facing some confusion about using Spring Data Jpa with hibernate. is it mandatory to use explicitly the Entitmanager? or the spring data repositories are enough?if you have some references about the good practise in using them both, it will be very helpful.

Comment: > is it mandatory to use explicitly the Entitmanager? or the spring data repositories are enough?
Roughly, Spring Data JPA Repository is more high-level abstraction than JPA entity manager.
While both would work, if possible, please, consider using the more high-level abstraction — Spring Data JPA Repository. Please, refer to the question: [Spring + hibernate versus Spring Data JPA: Are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012437/spring-hibernate-versus-spring-data-jpa-are-they-different).

Comment: @zakzak, by the way, are you sure that `Teacher` may have only one `Course`: `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "officialTeacher") private Course course;`? In my humble opinion, one `Teacher` may have many `Courses` (`0..*`).

Comment: I was only trying the differents possible associations between the two entities.In another example I have a Teacher can give many courses......

Answer (score 0):

I face this scenario once. I even noticed that changing to CascadeType.MERGE also works. I search on this and come to know that PERSIST assumes Teacher objects is already created and it just assigned teacherID to Course object. PERSIST means just put Teacher reference in Course object. You can also see this like it provides functionality that Course object should not update Teacher object. Teacher object should be updated separately.

Changing to MERGE update reference as well as Teacher object. 
CascadeType.ALL works because of MERGE.